# Call Scala Intellij Refresh Action From some other plugin

Tags: scala, sbt, intellij-plugin, intellij-scala

The requirement is to call Scala sbt plugin action (**Refresh Action**) and intelliJ **synchronize all** action from a custom plugin. As described [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206780745-Is-it-possible-to-trigger-function-action-of-another-plugin-from-a-plugin-), we can use below syntax to call Actions of other plugins from our custom plugin :-

```
ActionManager.getInstance().getAction(IdeActions.ACTION_COPY_REFERENCE);
```

Is there any way to figure out Action name and ids for functionalities that are highlighted in red blocks in below screenshot :-

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action is `com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.action.RefreshAllExternalProjectsAction` with id `ExternalSystem.RefreshAllProjects` (see `ExternalSystemActions.xml`)

To trigger a project refresh programmatically, you don't need to call the action. You can use `com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil#refreshProjects`

In IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 you may also use the experimental `com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.autoimport.ExternalSystemProjectTracker` API via `AutoImportProjectTracker.getInstance(???).scheduleProjectRefresh()`